# How to set dynamic text's z coordinate actionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, text, actionscript, coordinate

I'm trying to figure out how to set z coordinate of a dynamic text. x and y are possible. For example, I have a dynamic text with instance name of greetMe. I can set it's y and x position by

```
greetMe.y = 100;
greetMe.x = 200;
```

Though there's no error when I tried

```
greetMe.z = -100
```

, it is still not working. I tried to see the transform button but the menu is lock or unclickable. Is there any way to set the z-coordinate of a dynamic text?

I just wanted to hide first my dynamic object behind then when the user click a button, it will show up.

---

Thanks to sweet. The best idea is to set its visibility false then when the button has been clicked, it will show up by visibility of true.

```
greetMe.visible = false;
```

then... to make it visible...

```
greetMe.visible = true;
```

Comment: You could also just addChild to make it visible and then removeChild when done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like all you want to do is hide the `textField` initially and reveal it later. If this is the case you can simply set the field's `visible` property.

```
// Hide the field initially
greetMe.visible = false;  

// And show it when required
greetMe.visible = true;
```

If you need to put the `textfield` behind your button, you can use the `swapChildren` method of `DisplayList`. From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#swapChildren)):

> Swaps the z-order (front-to-back order) of the two specified child
>   objects. All other child objects in the display object container
>   remain in the same index positions.

`swapChildren(greetMe, myButton);`

Or you could use `setChildIndex` to ensure the textField is at the bottom of the `displayList` like so ([documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex)):

```
setChildIndex(greetMe, 0);
```

Comment: thanks sweet.
The dynamic text is far from that button.

I made it right now. thanks for help anyway.
what i just did is
greetMe.z = -1*(1000);

Comment: Is the idea just to hide it initially? If so you can just set the visibility to false.

Comment: greetMe.visible = false; Much cleaner than messing around with the z position ;)

Comment: that works... thanks you so much for that idea. I'm just a newbie anyway in as3